# Ajax result on FB login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below code is working fine but sometimes stops working, after refresh its starts again.

What it does that on Dom.ready it asks for facebook permissions and display results of user based of fb id, but this code somtimes stops working. May be i am doing too much on dom. Not working means success message not returns and after refresh,it starts again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

         //debugger;

         FB.init({
          appId : appId,
          status : true,
          cookie : true,
          oauth : true
          });
          FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1000});

         FB.getLoginStatus (onCheckLoginStatus);

        };

       function onCheckLoginStatus(response)
        {
         //debugger;

         if (response.status != "connected")
         {
          top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent (canvasPage) + "&scope=user_photos,friends_photos";
         }
         else
         {
          // Start the application (this is just demo code)!
          //$(document.body).append ("<p>Authorized!</p>");
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {


          //$("#usr").append(response.id);


           $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "display.php",
            data: "&fd="+response.id,             
            dataType: "text",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(res){                    
                $("#rescon").html(res); 
            }

           });

          });

         }
        }
});
```

Comment: try debugging to see if facebook api is causing problems or the AJAX request .. Hint: use console ..

Comment: No, its not. Performance is low, something hangs the browser for seconds